# Binding to last array element

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf, xaml, data-binding

So far, i have an `ObservableCollection<T>` for objects. 
I always want to display the last inserted element into a `TextBlock`. I implemented two solutions in XAML, but both not working:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=entries.Last().message, FallbackValue=...}" />

<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=entries[entries.Length-1].message, FallbackValue=...}" />
```

This one works, but references the first entry:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=entries[0].message, FallbackValue=...}" />
```

Am i missing something? Is it possible to do with pure XAML?

Comment: Not that I know of. Possible options are using a Converter or a property in your view model that returns the last element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Solution 1 :*

You can use a custom converter to achieve this :

**Converter class :**

```
class LastItemConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        IEnumerable<object> items = value as IEnumerable<object>;
        if (items != null)
        {
            return items.LastOrDefault();
        }
        else return Binding.DoNothing;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Xaml :**

```
 <Application.Resources>
        <local:LastItemConverter  x:Key="LastItemConverter" />
 </Application.Resources>

 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=entries, Converter={StaticResource LastItemConverter}}" />
```

*Solution 2 :*

The other way is to create a new property in your model that returns the entry :

```
public Object LastEntry => entries.LastOrDefault();
```

**Xaml :**

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=LastEntry, ... " />
```

Comment: In case of the property one would want to fire change notifications for said property in case of `CollectionChanged`.